# Is my android emulator's internet not working because I'm on hotspot?

Tags: android, networking

My internet is not working on Android emulator.  I've already looked this up and added the google dns setting, still doesn't work. It was working well a couple of minutes ago then it just stopped working.

I am using the emulator on my laptop, and my laptop is connected to my personal cell phone's hotspot. My personal cell phone is an android too. Could there be something happening between my personal phone and the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

try to disconnect your mobile data and wifi connection on your avd emulator and try to reconnect again, if it does not work you should reboot your avd emulator or try to manually close your running avd emulator and open it again.